# prestashop tax behaviour, How to apply Tax on Tax?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have problem to add taxes in my project..

I want to add first excise duty as 12% to my product.

And then Apply vat as 5% on total amount.

In product pries we can apply only one tax. How should i do this ?

I tried one after another Behavior but applying one tax who should i can apply another tax.

Answer (score 0):

i promise you you can apply tax calculations on a certain amount multiple times. 
if i am selling an item that cost me $100 to make and I add tax of 20% for profits the price would then be $120.If I then include 5% vat it would be 120*(100+5)/100  which is 126. Good luck

Comment: Yes sir.. but how i can apply in prestashop ?

Comment: well then you could do it like this... 20% is tax 1 and 5% is tax 2 to add them together before you apply tax you add them together like this . . .20%    +    5%     +   20% of 5%  is 1%... so then you get the 26% and you then can apply your 1 tax value(26%) to your prestashop